# Text messaging is not enabled on this device

Tags: iphone, sms

I followed this tutorial : http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/
 and I got the alert 'Text messaging is not enabled on this device'.

I have imported the MessageUI framework, "MessageUI/MessageUI.h", and MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate in my .h file. From what I read online it seems that people are able to view the MFMessageComposeViewController.

```
//.h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
...

@interface DateDetailsViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
...

//.m file
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"testing";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12345678", @"87654321", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
...
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        break;
    case MessageComposeResultFailed:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp" message:@"Unknown Error"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
        break;
    case MessageComposeResultSent:

        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Is there anything that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run it on a device or on the simulator?

Comment: There's your problem right there as far as I know Joe! You need to run it on a phone. The error you're getting is not a programming error, but limitation of the simulator.

Comment: Ahh I see. I'm working on an assignment and I can only use get a device for testing from my supervisor when I need one. She told me I'm supposed to see the message compose view the other day 8\ 
Thanks alot!

Comment: No worries -- You can send email using the same view -- so you could always test with email. I'll write this up as an answer, so please accept it so that people know your problem was solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MessageUI cannot send SMS from the simulator. Your application needs to be run on an iPhone with SMS service.